# Reproducing working curl in c# not working

Tags: c#, graphql, http-headers

I have been bashing at this and not found a solution. Reproducing this cURL.

```
curl  -H "Authorization: basic end6bXo5Mm0yenRiZDd3MjpiMzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzDg2MA=="  -H "Braintree-Version: 2019-01-01"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST https://payments.sandbox.braintree-api.com/graphql  -d "{\"query\": \"query { ping }\"}"
```

This comes back with the correct json reponse of

```
{"data":{"ping":"pong"},"extensions":{"requestId":"bfxxxxxxxxxx-4f7a-bff1-88a5af755856"}}
```

Writing this in c# I have.

```
public static string SendQuery(string queryString)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), Endpoint))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("BraintreeVersionHeader", "2021-06-18");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "basic " + Base64Encode(PublicKey + ":" + PrivateKey));
                
                request.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(queryString);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                return response.Status.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

The response contains.

```
Id = 50, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

Here are my input values.

```
querystring "{ \"query\": \"query { ping }\", \"variables\": {} }"
Endpoint https://payments.sandbox.braintree-api.com/graphql
Authorization basic end6bXo5Mm0yenRiZDd3MjpiMzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzDg2MA==
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        return response.Status.ToString();
```

`response` is a `Task`. So it's a process that hasen't finished yet. You should wait for the request to finish. A quick way to do that is

```
        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        return response.StatusCode;
```

Note that this changes the type of `response` from `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` to just `HttpResponseMessage` so you might need to adjust your code.
A better way to fix it would be to make your own method asynchronous and do

```
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        return response.StatusCode;
```

but that means also changing your calling code.

Comment: Hans Kilian, you are a star. It worked. Now just got to sort out getting the resulting data, errors, and extensions. There must be an easier way to do this with a code library. Can you recommend any?